# NextJS API calls work in dev but not in production after upgrading one package or changing yarn.lock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

For some reason my NextJS (hosted on Vercel) API calls are failing in production after a package update or rejigging the yarn lock. Every API call (even a simple hello world) is returning HTML like the index file. The package that started the issue is updating Mantine which is a client-side UI library. However, I've noticed this issue now occurs even if I keep all the packages locked to a specific version number and the `yarn.lock` changes at all.

This is the error I get in my Vercel logs but it doesn't really help since Memberstack is a client-side package that manages auth for us. And I only use the package on client-side pages.

```
info  - Loaded env from /var/task/.env
Memberstack React has initialized
Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"ReferenceError: window is not defined","reason":{"errorType":"ReferenceError","errorMessage":"window is not defined","stack":["ReferenceError: window is not defined","    at /var/task/node_modules/@memberstack/dom/lib/methods/index.js:45:5","    at new Promise (<anonymous>)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/@memberstack/dom/lib/methods/index.js:43:27)","    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)","    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)","    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)","    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)","    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)","    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/@memberstack/dom/lib/index.js:6:33)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: ReferenceError: window is not defined","    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1188:17)","    at process.emit (node:events:525:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
```

What the package.json looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@amplitude/analytics-browser": "^1.9.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.10.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.17",
    "@mantine/carousel": "^6.0.6",
    "@mantine/core": "^6.0.6",
    "@mantine/hooks": "^6.0.6",
    "@mantine/next": "^6.0.6",
    "@mantine/notifications": "^6.0.6",
    "@memberstack/react": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/node": "18.15.11",
    "@types/react": "18.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "airtable": "^0.11.6",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.37.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "next": "13.3.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.3"
  }
```

I've attempted deleting the `yarn.lock` and reinstalling all the packages, but that breaks API calls in production as well. The only thing that works is literally copying the same `yarn.lock` file that worked previously in production and using that when deploying.

So basically I'm stuck with not touching the `yarn.lock` file ever or touching certain packages otherwise production breaks.

I'm trying to figure out if there's an issue with the packages I'm installing, is there something I need to do with yarn when installing/upgrading the packages? Or is this some compatibility issue between NextJS and some of the packages I'm using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `/var/task/node_modules/@memberstack/dom/lib/methods/index.js:45:5` is trying to access `window` however because NextJS does SSR, it is likely undefined.

I suggest adding `typeof window === undefined` above the call to window OR using the [dynamic package](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) from next and disabling SSR when importing memberstack

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look into this. At the moment, I don't use this package on any API calls, so I'm not sure what I can do about it. My guess is that there's some interaction with the server-side components that's causing this package to fire...

Comment: Thanks again for this! Looks like the issue is somethign to do with the UI library and Tailwind interactions in the _document file. My guess is some SSR is occurring that causes that package to fire.